# Printing 10 characters from a String at a time in MIPS

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

I'm having issues solving these small task I got. Basically I got a board stored in 1 line, and I need to print 10 characters in 1 line and then break and so on. It's a board of 10 x 10, so it should run 10 times printing 10 character lines.

Something like this:

```
board:
    .asciiz     "    x xx   x  x      x  x  xxx x  x         x   x         x xxxx  x x       x   xx    x         x xx"
```

For this we got handed 2 subroutines, print and printlf. print takes in $a0 the string to print, and in $a1 the length, so I just need to jal print once I get the correct characters stored in the registers.

I was reading how to solve this on the internet and got to this [source](http://davidlovesprogramming.blogspot.de/2013/01/the-following-post-is-bit-more-complex.html).

It uses lb to load byte by byte the string on a register. So I tried to loop every 10 characters with a counter. And if the character is 0, then it's the end of the string apparently. I'm not really sure about this, though that source says it's like that.

```
   li $a1, 10   #the length of the string it's supposed to print
   la $t0, board
   

count:
   lb $a0, 0($t0)
   li $t1, 0        #for counting characters
   addi $t0, $t0, 1
   addi $t1, $t1, 1
   beq $t1, $a1, endLoop
   j count  

endLoop:
   jal print      #doing this should print whatever is in $a0 if I'm not mistaken
   jal print_lf   #prints a line break
   beqz $a0, endString
   j count

 endString:
   jr $ra
```

This doesn't seem to work on QTSpim, it never exits, just keeps on running.

Anyone kind enough to maybe know a solution to this small task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `count` loop makes no sense to me whatsoever. It's just a convoluted way to set `t1` to `10` which you then don't even use. And it only works once. Try to write it in C or pseudocode, or if all else fails, draw a flowchart. Once you got the logic, go code it.

Comment: When you call `print`, $a0 should be the address of the string to print. You are loading a character value into $a0.

Comment: @Jester, the `count` loop is also a convoluted way to increment $t0 by 10.

Comment: $t0 isn't saved across the function calls. You should use $s0 for the board. Also $a1 isn't saved, so you need to reload it before each call to `print`.

Comment: Actually `$t1` is even zeroed in the loop so it's only ever going to be incremented to 1 then zeroed and it will never reach `$a1` so that looks like an endless loop. Except for `$t0` getting out of range and the `lb` faulting.